# Error using http post request with void output in Karate Framework

Tags: karate

I try to run a post request that does not have an output body. The output is void. I get the 200 answer but then it fails. I have already spoken to my colleagues at the company and they have indicated that it is not possible to execute these types of requests in karate. Is it a bug on the part of karate's developers? Here's the error:

[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 3][route: {s}->REMOVED:443] can be kept alive indefinitely

[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-3: set socket timeout to 0

[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 3][route: {s}->REMOVED:443][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException, http call failed after 1601 milliseconds for URL:REMOVED

[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException

Answer (score 0):

There's a new version just released: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v1.0.0 - so try that first.

Do update here if that works. That said - the log you provided does not help at all. The best thing you can do is follow this process, so that the developers get a decent chance to understand what you mean by "does not have an output body" and "void": https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue